# I want add multiple Data Items of same date in single Card View in Android

Tags: android-studio

I want data to be displayed as shown in image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ObS.png)

I want to add multiple item of same date in single card view instead of creating another card view for the item of same date

I have tried in Android Studio grouping recycler view called as sanctioned Recycler view where I used date as header but it's not the solution

```
My Adapter Class

   private Context mContext;
            List<ListItem> consolidatedList = new ArrayList<>();

            public AttendanceAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> 
            consolidatedList) {
                this.consolidatedList = consolidatedList;
                this.mContext = context;
            }

               @Override
                public RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
               onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                    LayoutInflater inflater = 
              LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

                    switch (viewType) {
                        case ListItem.TYPE_GENERAL:
                            View v1 = 
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_adapter_layout, parent,
                                    false);
                            viewHolder = new GeneralViewHolder(v1);
                            break;

                        case ListItem.TYPE_DATE:
                            View v2 = 
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.attn_item_header, parent, false);
                            viewHolder = new DateViewHolder(v2);
                            break;
                    }

                return viewHolder;
            }

     @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
       viewHolder, int position) 
            {

                switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {

                    case ListItem.TYPE_GENERAL:

           GeneralItem generalItem   = (GeneralItem) 
           consolidatedList.get(position);

          GeneralViewHolder generalViewHolder=
          (GeneralViewHolder) viewHolder;

         //generalViewHolder.txt_date.setText( 
          generalItem.getAttendance_data().getDate());

          generalViewHolder.txt_month.setText( 
          generalItem.getAttendance_data().getMonth_name());

          generalViewHolder.txt_date.setText( 
          generalItem.getAttendance_data().getDate_no());

          generalViewHolder.txt_out.setText( 
          generalItem.getAttendance_data().getAttn_out_time());

          generalViewHolder.txt_in.setText(
          generalItem.getAttendance_data().getAttn_In_time());


         generalViewHolder.txtreason.setText          
         (generalItem.getAttendance_data().getRemark());

                        break;

                    case ListItem.TYPE_DATE:
             DateItem dateItem = (DateItem)                    
             consolidatedList.get(position);
             DateViewHolder dateViewHolder = (DateViewHolder) viewHolder;


        dateViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(dateItem.getDate());
                        // Populate date item data here
                        break;
                }
            }

        class DateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                protected TextView txtTitle;

                public DateViewHolder(View v) {
                    super(v);
                    this.txtTitle = (TextView) 
            v.findViewById(R.id.attn_date);

                }
            }

            // View holder for general row item
            class GeneralViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

              protected TextView 
              txt_in,txtreason,txt_out,txt_date,txt_month;

                public GeneralViewHolder(View v) {
                   super(v);
                    this.txt_in =v.findViewById(R.id.attn_in_txt);
                    this.txt_out=v.findViewById(R.id.attn_out_txt);
                    this.txtreason=v.findViewById(R.id.attn_reason_txt);
                    this.txt_date=v.findViewById(R.id.date_view);
                    this.txt_month=v.findViewById(R.id.month_view);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                return consolidatedList.get(position).getType();
            }


    @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
            return consolidatedList != null ? consolidatedList.size() : 0;
            }

        }


  MainActivity.Java


    public class CurrentMonth extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        attn_list_data_cur_month();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        updateUi();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}

     public void attn_list_data_cur_month(){
    try {
        this.connection=createConnection();
        Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
        Calendar current_month_data = Calendar.getInstance();
        current_month_data.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        //Calendar current_month_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        //current_month_date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,0);
        n=current_month_data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String current_month_year = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM- 
        yyyy").format(current_month_data.getTime());
        String month_name=currentMonth.getText().toString();

        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            String date = i + "-" + current_month_year;

            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from 
            MATTN_MAS where ATTN_DATE='" + date + "' and Username='" + 
            Username + "'");

            String Attn_Type;

            if (resultSet.next()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    Attn_Type = resultSet.getString(8);
                    String Time = null;
                    String Reason = resultSet.getString(11);

                    if (Attn_Type.equals("I")) {
                        String Attn_Type_In = "I";
                        String Attn_Type_Out = null;
                 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
                 String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();

                  myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type_In, 
                  date, Reason, Attn_Type_Out, i, date_no, month_name));

                 } else {

                  String Attn_Type_Out = "O";
                        String Attn_Type_In = null;
                  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
                  String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();

                  myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type_In, 
                  date, Reason, Attn_Type_Out, i, date_no, month_name));

                   }
                }
            } else {
                Attn_Type = "Absent";
                String Time = null;
                String Reason = null;
                String out = null;

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
                String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();

                myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type, date, Reason, 
                out, i, date_no, month_name));
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("my Error"+e);
    }
}


    public void updateUi(){
    //sortedData= (List<PojoOfJsonArray>) 
    PojoOfJsonArray.sortList(myOptions);
    HashMap<String, List<Attendance_Data>> groupedHashMap = 
     groupDataIntoHashMap(myOptions);

    for (String date1 : groupedHashMap.keySet()) {
        DateItem dateItem = new DateItem();
        dateItem.setDate(date1);
        consolidatedList.add(dateItem);

        for (Attendance_Data pojoOfJsonArray : groupedHashMap.get(date1)) 
        {
            GeneralItem generalItem = new GeneralItem();
            generalItem.setAttendance_data(pojoOfJsonArray);
            consolidatedList.add(generalItem);
        }
    }
    adapter = new AttendanceAdapter(this, consolidatedList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    attn_report_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    attn_report_view.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

  private HashMap<String, List<Attendance_Data>> 
  groupDataIntoHashMap(List<Attendance_Data> listOfPojosOfJsonArray) {

    HashMap<String, List<Attendance_Data>> groupedHashMap = new HashMap<> 
    ();

    for (Attendance_Data pojoOfJsonArray : listOfPojosOfJsonArray) {

        String hashMapKey = pojoOfJsonArray.getDate();

        if (groupedHashMap.containsKey(hashMapKey)) {
            // The key is already in the HashMap; add the pojo object
            // against the existing key.
            groupedHashMap.get(hashMapKey).add(pojoOfJsonArray);
        } else {

            List<Attendance_Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(pojoOfJsonArray);
            groupedHashMap.put(hashMapKey, list);
        }
    }
    return groupedHashMap;
 }
```

I want to add multiple items of same date in same single single card view but instead it is creating multiple Card View for multiple items of same date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yeah I found the solution it worked perfect for Me.....we 
have to just make changes to the card View by removing 
spaces..

.

like this below...

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  card_view:cardMaxElevation="0.1dp"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:background="#303030"
  card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
  android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_2"
  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_2">


    <...Your All Text Boxes and further Layout inside this 
    cardView...>


  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

 and I have add Header for each CardView....and it looks like 
 this
```

[Outout is shown in below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szWmI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use RecyclerView Multiple ViewTypes. for detail please check this [example](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example).

Also visit [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-dfba3979050) example.

Comment: Will it add multiple data of same date in single cardView......I want data according to the date...